# To ignore text inside double quote in antlr 2

Tags: antlr

How can I  ignore text inside double quote in antlr 2 . 
for example:
I want to ignore "something random"  , "some another random" type text which is inside double quote . How can I do this without my parser failing .

Comment: Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: cant you write a roll/token that does nothing with them? :
Skip: "."
this is a simple syntax...you can create something more complex for other options

Answer (score 0):

You could do what antlr would do for an XML parser:
form island grammars and lexer modes.

Note that this only works if there are no nested quotes:

As soon as you encounter a " you do a pushmode action and switch to a mode that skips everything except ", and switch back to regular when you see another ". This isn't elegant but should work rather well.